# DECODE - REMOVE NULLs

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

Please help me remove nulls from both the columns

```
SELECT Decode(pk.property_name, 'msisdn', pv.text_value) MSISDN,
Decode(pk.property_name, 'BAN', pv.text_value) BAN
FROM PROPERTY_VALUE pv, PROPERTY_KEY pk 
WHERE pv.entity_id IN 
(select entity_id from property_value pv where pv.text_value in('ConsumerUnauthenticated')) 
and pv.property_key_id = pk.property_key_id
```

This is resulting in a table MSISDN and BAN. Both these columns are containing NULL and NOT NULL values. I want to eliminate NULL from the resulting table. Please help.

```
BAD - 

MSISDN    BAN
null      xyz
null      abc
1213      null
null      def
1211      null
```

AND I want my result to be

```
MSISDN    BAN
1213      xyz
1211      abc
          def
```

Comment: What server you are using ?

Comment: Oracle DB 11g - NOT SURE

Comment: bu your requirement and above query doesn't match ? what exactly you want ? what are you trying to do with above query ?

Comment: I got the result from the query I have written above. Now I have no idea what to do next

Comment: Your results don't appear to conform to normal database data structures.  Your *desired* output suggests that you're forcing `MSISDN = 1213` to become associated to `BNA = xyz` for no real reason, and that `BAN = def` is associated to `nothing` but that somehow it's different from `NULL`.  Do you really want ***two*** output tables?  One of the unique non-null MSISDNs, and one of the unique non-null BANs?

Comment: I just want one output table and having two columns only -  One of the unique non-null MSISDNs, and one of the unique non-null BANs

Comment: You can't do that in your query. You have to do that in your application's UI instead.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be doing that. Check the comments under your question. But here's the query:

```
SELECT MSISDN, BAN
FROM (
    SELECT pv.text_value MSISDN, rownum rn
    FROM PROPERTY_VALUE pv, PROPERTY_KEY pk 
    WHERE pv.entity_id IN (select entity_id from property_value pv where pv.text_value in('ConsumerUnauthenticated')) 
    AND pv.property_key_id = pk.property_key_id
    AND pk.property_name = 'msisdn'
    AND pv.text_value IS NOT NULL
) FULL OUTER JOIN (    
    SELECT pv.text_value BAN, rownum rn
    FROM PROPERTY_VALUE pv, PROPERTY_KEY pk 
    WHERE pv.entity_id IN (select entity_id from property_value pv where pv.text_value in('ConsumerUnauthenticated')) 
    AND pv.property_key_id = pk.property_key_id
    AND pk.property_name = 'ban'
    AND pv.text_value IS NOT NULL
) USING (rn)
ORDER BY rn;
```